# Timing based on upper or lower part of sun/moon

Tags: terminology, definition, sunrise, sunset

When you time an astronomical event, such as the moon/sun rising above the horizon, do you note the time when the the first sliver breeches the horizon or when the bottom of the moon/sun just becomes visible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the first one, i.e. as soon as the heavenly body can be first seen. Here a definition from http://www.ga.gov.au/scientific-topics/astronomical/astronomical-definitions

> Sunrise is defined as the instant in the morning under ideal meteorological conditions, with standard refraction of the Sun's rays, when the upper edge of the sun's disk is coincident with an ideal horizon.